# Azure cloud service Web App Not found -404

Tags: security, azure, dns, azure-cloud-services, web-application-firewall

I've a webapp hosted in azure cloud service.

We would like to put the WAF infront of web app per setup below:

1. We have created a bladomain.com.au
2. The DNS record points to IMPERVA IP address
3. IMPERVA then points to bla.azurewebsites.net

If I access the site directly using bla.azurewebsites.net, it works with no issue.

However when I try to access bla.zurewebsites.net, it shows below:
[image]

I tried adding bladomain.com.au to azure web app custom domain but it shows the error message below:

> Error:DNS record for 'bladomain.com.au' that points to
>   'bla.azurewebsites.net' could not be located. If you want to configure
>   A record you must first create CNAME record with your DNS provider..."

Bit confused with error message above, as CNAME for bladomain.com.au should point to Imperva....

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I believe that you will need to setup Azure WebApp to respond domain with some Imperva endpoint. Look, your domain will point to Imperva, then the Imperva server will "redirect" to Azure, so, Azure will respond to Imperva, not to your Domain. Double check this at some Imperva doc.

Comment: That would not work as we need to get host header of the domain that's been requested.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you move your site regions, for example you had your site on Europe DC and you moved to US DC

It takes some time for the DNS to switch the IP address of your new Website and point it to the right DataCenter

It usually takes from 10 min to 2 hour for the changes to sync across the glob

Answer (score 1):

We have similar problem, we are getting 404 error after more than 48 hours. It works after only, we run `ipconfig /flushdns` on client machine. It works smoothly after that, but it virtually impossible to tell every client to do flushdns.

Comment: Update: We have to make explicit entry xyz.com and www.xyz.com in windows azure custom domain section. Azure doesn't automatically map www.xyz.com to xyz.com. After adding two entries for same domain, thing is working instantly.

Comment: super important comment, you saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you simply need to do one of below:

```
 1. Create awverify.yourdomain and point it's CNAME to azure web apps. OR
 2. Update your domain CNAME to point to azure Web Apps.
```